# Configuration trouble: PHP through mod_fcgid on CentOS 5.3

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, mod-fcgid

I've been Googling and researching the topic for quite a while but found only one thorough guide... That don't work.

I want to run `PHP` through mod_fcgid on `Apache2` - `CentOS 5.3`.

With my current configuration I get `500 Internal Server Error` on `.php`-files. Could you please help me figure out why? :)

**httpd.conf:**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all

    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/php5/php-fcgi-starter .php
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/cgi-bin/php5/php-fcgi-starter:**

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/etc/
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

**php-cgi -v:**

```
PHP 5.2.6 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May  2 2008 16:01:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.29, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by ionCube Ltd.
```

`SeLinux` is turned of.

**EDIT:** Logs...

```
[Mon Nov 02 05:17:49 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 02 05:17:53 2009] [error] Not even headers for me :(
[Mon Nov 02 05:17:54 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /var/www/html/phpinfo.php with wrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/php5/php-fcgi-starter
[Mon Nov 02 05:17:54 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: server /var/www/html/phpinfo.php(13917) started
[Mon Nov 02 05:17:57 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/html/phpinfo.php(13917) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 120
```

**SuExec_log:**

```
[2009-11-02 04:55:27]: uid: (10001/www) gid: (2524/2524) cmd: php5
[2009-11-02 04:55:27]: target uid/gid (10001/2524 or 2523) mismatch with directory (10001/2523) or program (0/0)
[2009-11-02 04:57:19]: uid: (10001/www) gid: (2524/2524) cmd: php-fcgi-starter
[2009-11-02 04:57:19]: target uid/gid (10001/2524 or 2523) mismatch with directory (0/0) or program (0/0)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Show us yer logs, luv!

Comment: Sorry, now you have them.

Comment: Are you using SuExec by chance? Take a look at your suexec.log, if it contains an error message for your script.

Comment: It seems I do use SuExec... Added the log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUExec is requiring that the directory (`/var/www/html/`) and the binary (`/var/www/cgi-bin/php5/php-fcgi-starter`) be owned by the same user/group.  Looks like `10001/2523` owns the dir, and root owns php-fcgi-starter.  Fix that, or turn off SUExec.